# Non-parametric test for interaction of two continuous variables on a third continuous variable

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, interaction, nonparametric

I have two continuous variables `a` and `b` and I would like to test whether they non-linearly interact to affect a dependent variable `c`.  Without loss of generality, let's assume that `a` and `b` are positively correlated with `c`. Then there are 3 possibilities:

1. `a` and `b` have a positive interaction (e.g. `c = a + b + 2ab - 1`, `c = 2a + 3b + 2 a / b + 3`)
2. `a` and `b` have a negative interaction (e.g. `c = a + b - 2ab - 1`, `c = 2a + 3b - 2 a / b + 3`)
3. `a` and `b` do not have a consistent interaction or have no interaction (e.g. `c = a + 2b + Normal(0, 1)`,  `c = a + b + ab(a - b)`, `c = a + b + d` where `d` is independent of `a` and `b`, `c = 2a + b + 5`).

I would like both a two-tailed test for interaction that gives a low p value in cases 1 and 2 but not 3, and one-tailed tests for positive interaction (low p value for case 1 only) and negative interaction (low p value for case 2 only).  How should this test be formulated?

Note that this is more complicated than testing whether two continuous variables are [independent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/how-do-i-test-that-two-continuous-variables-are-independent) or [non-linearly related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35893/how-do-i-test-a-nonlinear-association), although ideas from those posts might be helpful in solving this problem.

Comment: What would you see as a parametric test, perhaps a linear regression on the interaction term?

Comment: Yeah, testing the coefficient on the interaction term. 7 years later, I'd probably just use the parametric version :) I mean you could always rank transform, but you can never get away from making some kind of assumption about the nature of the interaction.